# How to append XML (String) to XmlEventWriter (StAX) which already created the start of document

Tags: java, xml, stax, woodstox

In order to create big XML files, we decided to make use of the StAX API. The basic structure is build by using the low-level api's: createStartDocument(), createStartElement(). This works as expected.

However, in some cases we like to append existing XML data which resides in a String (retrieved from database). The following snippet illustrates this:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String... args) throws XMLStreamException {
        XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        XMLEventWriter eventWriter = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(writer);

        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createStartDocument("UTF-8", "1.0"));
        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createStartElement("ns0", "http://example.org", "root"));
        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createNamespace("ns0", "http://example.org"));

        //In here, we want to append a piece of XML which is stored in a string variable.
        String xml = "<fragments><fragment><data>This is pure text.</data></fragment></fragments>";
        eventWriter.add(inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(xml)));

        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndDocument());

        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }
}
```

With the above code, depending on the implementation, we are not getting the expected result:

- Woodstox:  The following exception is thrown:'Can not output XML declaration, after output has already been done'. It seems that the XMLEventReader starts off with a startDocument event, but since a startDocument event was already triggered programatically, it throws the error.
- JDK: It appends `<?xml version="1.0" ... <fragments><fragment>...` -> Which leads to invalid XML.

I have also tried to append the XML by using:

```
eventFactory.createCharacters(xml);
```

The problem here is that even though the XML is appended, the < and > are transformed into &lt and &gt. Therefore, this results in invalid XML.

Am I missing an API that allows me to simply append a String as XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first consume any StartDocument if necessary:

```
    String xml = "<fragments><fragment><data>This is pure text.</data></fragment></fragments>";
    XMLEventReader xer = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(xml));
    if (xer.peek().isStartDocument())
    {
        xer.nextEvent();
    }
    eventWriter.add(xer);
```

Comment: You are a true live saver! Just to know it was right in front of me O_o

Comment: In the end, I ended up creating a FilteredEventReader since I also had to skip the EndDocument event. Otherwise, it would close of the complete xml.

Comment: Using this example I aways got this exception javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: No open start element, when trying to write end element